# how to run dlib face recognition with gpu

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, face-recognition, dlib

I have installed visual studio 2019, and Cuda 10.1 and TensorFlow 2.1.0 and I still can't run face recognition with GPU, can someone give me a complete guide on the steps to use GPU instead of CPU.

note: I'm using windows 10, my GPU is gtx1050 and I am using anaconda spider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this by these steps using an anaconda enviroment:

cuda 10.2  installed

python (3.7.7)

conda install pip

conda install tensorflow (latest 2.1.0)

conda install tensorflow-gpu

pip install imutils

pip install opencv-python

pip install opencv-contrib-python

pip install dlib

pip install face_recognition

Answer (score 2):

As Adrian Rosebrock mentioned at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/18/face-recognition-with-opencv-python-and-deep-learning/, it is better to build Dlib from source, so the library is aware of the presence of the exact GPU in your system. My guess is - during the building process, it probes the capabilities of the GPU through the CUDA driver and builds and installs accordingly.

git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
cd dlib
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DDLIB_USE_CUDA=1 -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1
cmake --build .
cd ..
python setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS --yes DLIB_USE_CUDA

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should install tensorflow-gpu package instead of tensorflow.

If your tf is installed correctly, you can run face recognition in gpu within deepface. You can test it with allocate memory function.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
DeepFace.allocateMemory()
```

If everything is OK, then it returns "DeepFace will run on GPU" message.

All face recogntion models except Dlib will run on tensorflow-gpu. You can run face recognition with verification function.

```
from deepface import DeepFace
models = ["VGG-Face", "Facenet", "OpenFace", "DeepFace", "DeepID", "Dlib"]
obj = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = models[0])
print(obj)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'deepface.DeepFace' has no attribute 'allocateMemory'`