# How to run a script on Linux through a discrete Nvidia graphics card?

Tags: python, linux, face-recognition

I am using the "Face-recognition" library, with the "cnn" parameter set

```
locations = face_recognition.face_locations(frame, model='cnn')
```

How can I make this script work through a discrete video card, and not through the built-in one?.

Run through
`optirun python main.py`
and
`primusrun python main.py`
does not return any results, when checking usage I only get

```
nvidia-smi
...

|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      7626      G   /usr/lib/Xorg                                 5MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Accordingly, the script itself does not use a discrete graphics card

I am weak in Linux, but I want to know this beautiful OS, so I will be very grateful for your answers.

The script:

```
def detected():

    # data = pickle.loads(open('user_1_encodings.pickle', 'rb').read())

    cams = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    not_identify = []

    while True:
        ret, frame = cams.read()

        locations = face_recognition.face_locations(frame, model='cnn')
        encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(frame, locations)

        for face_encoding, face_location in zip(encodings, locations):
            # user_encodings = user_data['encodings']
            # result = face_recognition.compare_faces(user_encodings, face_encoding)
            result = False
            green = [0, 255, 0]
            blue = [255, 0, 0]
            red = [0, 0, 255]

            if any(result):
                print(result)
                match = user_data['name']
                left_top = (face_location[3], face_location[0])
                right_bottom = (face_location[1], face_location[2])
                cv2.rectangle(frame, left_top, right_bottom, green, 2)

                text_x = face_location[3]
                text_y = face_location[0] - 10  
                font_scale = 0.5
                font_thickness = 1
                font_face = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL
                text_size, _ = cv2.getTextSize(match, font_face, font_scale, font_thickness)
                text_width, text_height = text_size


                rect_left_top = (text_x-1, text_y+5)
                rect_right_bottom = (text_x + text_width+5, text_y - text_height-5)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, rect_left_top, rect_right_bottom, (255, 255, 255), -1)


                cv2.putText(frame, match, (text_x, text_y), font_face, font_scale, (255, 0, 0), font_thickness)

            else:
                print('NOT OK')
                print(face_location)
                match = 'Unknown'

                top, right, bottom, left = face_location
                face = frame[top:bottom, left:right]
                pil_image = Image.fromarray(face)

                print(pil_image)
                not_identify.append(pil_image)
                print(not_identify)
                if len(not_identify) > 3:
                    #
                    if result is False:
                        not_identify = []
                    else:
                        data = result
                        not_identify = []


                left_top = face_location[3], face_location[0]
                right_bottom = (face_location[1], face_location[2])

                cv2.rectangle(frame, left_top, right_bottom, red, 2)


            text_x = face_location[3]
            text_y = face_location[0] - 10  

            font_scale = 0.5
            font_thickness = 1
            font_face = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL
            text_size, _ = cv2.getTextSize(match, font_face, font_scale, font_thickness)
            text_width, text_height = text_size

            rect_left_top = (text_x-1, text_y+5)
            rect_right_bottom = (text_x + text_width+5, text_y - text_height-5)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, rect_left_top, rect_right_bottom, (255, 255, 255), -1)

            cv2.putText(frame, match, (text_x, text_y), font_face, font_scale, (255, 0, 0), font_thickness)

    cv2.imshow('scan', frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if k == ord('q'):
        break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    detected()
```

Benchmarks all work well, through `optirun` run from a discrete graphics card, which means that the drivers are standing and working.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      6351      G   /usr/lib/Xorg                                24MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6355      G   glxspheres64                                  2MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: For a deep learning model (as I suspect seeing `'cnn'` as a parameter), this typically involves loading the weights & biases onto the GPU, then running inference. If the script itself "does not use a discrete graphics card", then you need to make changes. However, I have no idea what this script looks like, nor am I familiar with this "`face-recognition`" library. Some documentation links, as well as what `main.py` contains would help. As is, your question cannot be answered and requires more clarification. Please edit your post by creating a [mcve] or you risk your question being closed.

Comment: I added the script to my question

Comment: The face_recognition library appears to be based on dlib. `python -c 'import dlib; print(dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA)'` -- what's the result?

Comment: Also see [How to run dlib face recognition with gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450364/how-to-run-dlib-face-recognition-with-gpu); one could _almost_ argue this to be a duplicate.

Comment: print(dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA) - False

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think it would be a duplicate. One of the posts exactly matches this user's problem.

Comment: I have code running with the GPU, but it works from the built-in Intel graphics card, not the discrete Nvidia. The performance of the built-in video card is 1 frame in 15 seconds.

My question is how to make the processing go on the Nvidia graphics card and not Intel

Comment: @Roman The post that Charles linked explains how exactly to solve your problem. You need to ensure you install the right GPU libraries so that you can run it on the NVIDIA card.

Comment: Thank you for the amendment. I thought there was another question. Now I will try to study what is said on the link and give feedback

Comment: You need to recompile dlib with CUDA enabled. Not every answer on the linked question covers that, but some do; there also appear to be pertinent Google hits.

Comment: Your claims of running on the Intel GPU are not correct, dlib uses CUDA which only runs on Nvidia GPUs, not on Intel ones.